# If f is uniformly continuous in R. Then g (x, y) = f (x) -f (y) is uniformly continuous in R^2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-continuity

If $f$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, then $g(x,y) = f(x) - f(y)$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is this true or false?

I have no idea on how to approach this question, can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange Alan. Usually, people want to see the work you've done in order to help you better. You should tell us what you tried so far. This website is not here to solve homework problems

Comment: This problem is solved 95% of the way by just writing out all the definitions. Then you should be able to see the small leap you need to make.

Comment: sorry and thanks for the advices. Ican't see how but I'll continue learning.

Comment: @MaximeScott: of course this site is here to solve homework problems; otherwise, there wouldn't be hundreds of homework problems solved every day. All the OP needs to do is to write "I tried $1+1=2$" to avoid being caught by the *closing brigade*. And even then, someone will likely still do the homework before the question is closed (as it has already happened with this very question!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write out the definitions of what it means for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a function $g:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be uniformly continuous.

> The function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists$ $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x-y| < \delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Then we also have that

> The function $g: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall (x,y), (x',y') \in \mathbb{R^2}$ satisfying $|x-x'| + |y-y'| < \delta$ $\Rightarrow |g(x,y) - g(x',y')| < \varepsilon$

---

So we know that $f$ is uniformly continuous, i.e. $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists$ $\delta > 0$ such that

1. $\forall x,x' \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x-x'| < \delta_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(x')|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
2. $\forall y,y' \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|y-y'| < \delta_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(y)-f(y')|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Now we consider $g(x,y) = f(x) - f(y)$, then $$|g(x,y) - g(x',y')| = |f(x) - f(y) - f(x')+f(y')| \leq |f(x) - f(x')| + |f(y) - f(y')|$$

So simply set $\frac{\delta}{2}:=\max(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, then for $|x-x'| + |y-y'|<\delta$, we have $$|g(x,y) - g(x',y')| = |f(x) - f(y) - f(x')+f(y')| $$$$\leq |f(x) - f(x')| + |f(y) - f(y')| $$$$\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$ as required.

---

**Edit:** with these problems, it is usually a matter of writing out the definitions and using the triangle inequality.